# Invalid cast exception when getting nextpage of twitter friends

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, twitterizer

Hi I'm using twitterizer to get a list of friends for an authenticated user.
After some successful iterations of the while loop. I get an invalidcastexception when I call ResponseObject.NextPage. I am stumped as to why I am getting the error. Can anyone see why?

Code below.

```
    List<String> GetFriends(OAuthTokens tokens)
    {
        var result = new List<String>();
        TwitterResponse<TwitterUserCollection> friendsResponse = TwitterFriendship.Friends(tokens);
        if (friendsResponse.Result != RequestResult.Success)
        {
            return new List<string> {friendsResponse.ErrorMessage};

        }

        TwitterUserCollection friends = friendsResponse.ResponseObject;

        while (friends != null)
        {
            result.AddRange(friends.Select(x => x.Name));
            var y = friends.NextPage(); //ERROR HERE
            friendsResponse = y; 

            if (friendsResponse.Result != RequestResult.Success)
            {
                return new List<string> {friendsResponse.ErrorMessage};

            }
            friends = friendsResponse.ResponseObject;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug... NextPage will be removed from the next version of Twitterizer http://forums.twitterizer.net/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=475

Answer (score 1):

if this may help, I found that I had this exception when reading Geo Coordinates with latitude or longitude set to an integer value (without any ".").

The conversion to double raised an exception, so I changed this part of source code in Methods\Geo\Coordinate.cs :

```
if (count % 2 > 0)
{
    result.Add(new Coordinate());
    result[itemIndex].Latitude = (double)reader.Value;
}
else
{
    result[itemIndex].Longitude = (double)reader.Value;
}
```

to

```
if (count % 2 > 0)
{
    result.Add(new Coordinate());
    result[itemIndex].Latitude = System.Convert.ToDouble(reader.Value);
}
else
{
    result[itemIndex].Longitude = System.Convert.ToDouble(reader.Value);
}
```

and no more exception...